# jquery's selectable plugin

Tags: jquery

using jquery's selectable plugin, how to highlight kid nodes of the selected element rather than the element itself?

```
$('div:first').selectable();

<div>
 <div>
   <div class="highlightMe">
   </div>
   <div class="highlightMe2">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any chance of giving that second `<div>` a class? Right now it *is* doing the child nodes, the first child node contains both of the others.

Comment: What is this...OP and answerers have the same user name...

Answer (score 1):

yes, i should be like this

```
$('div:first').selectable();

<div>
 <div class="selectME">
   <div class="highlightMe">
   </div>
   <div class="highlightMe2">
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

and also, i forgot to mention, those should be highlighted differently, for example, highlightMe should change its background color and highlightMe2 - its border color.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for multiply posts but my bro doesn't eat cookie. here's the answer! ;)

```
.ui-selecting .highlightMe { 
    border: solid 3px #9eb7df;
}
.ui-selected .highlightMe { 
    border: solid 3px #9eb7df;
}
.ui-selecting .highlightMe2 { 
    background: #feca40; 
}
.ui-selected .highlightMe2 { 
    background: #feca40; 
}
```

something like that will work